# multiple group capture/modify with sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'd like to use `sed` to modify the output of `gcc -MM` which generates a dependency graph for C/C++ files.

The input looks like:

```
ThreadCrash.o : ThreadCrash.cpp ThreadCrash.h hdr1.h \
 ../inc/hdr2.h ../inc/hdr3.h \
 ../inc/hdr4.h ../inc/hdr4.h
```

And I need to make it look like:

```
ThreadCrash.o : \
ThreadCrash.cpp \
ThreadCrash.h \
hdr1.h \
../inc/hdr2.h \
../inc/hdr3.h \
../inc/hdr4.h \
../inc/hdr4.h
```

For the 'find' part of the substitute I've been trying to "repeat" capture groups like `(.*)*` but can't figure out how to form the replace string.

I'm not tied to sed so any simple approach, eg `awk` etc, would be greatly welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the replies, all good answers and all work.  Glenn's is the most elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space at the start of the line, then replace any space  followed by something other than a colon or backslash with space-backslash-newline-char sequence:

Using GNU sed:

```bsh
sed -E 's/^ //; s/ ([^:\\])/ \\\n\1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="" }
{
    gsub(/\\/,"")
    printf "%s ", $1
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {
        printf "%s \\\n", $i
    }
    print $NF
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ThreadCrash.o : \
ThreadCrash.cpp \
ThreadCrash.h \
hdr1.h \
../inc/hdr2.h \
../inc/hdr3.h \
../inc/hdr4.h \
../inc/hdr4.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems counter-intuitive, it might actually be simplest to stitch the dependency back into a single line (by rejoining the continuations), and then breaking it apart again by matching sequences of horizontal whitespace (with optional colon).

So given

```
$ cat input
ThreadCrash.o : ThreadCrash.cpp ThreadCrash.h hdr1.h \
 ../inc/hdr2.h ../inc/hdr3.h \
 ../inc/hdr4.h ../inc/hdr4.h
```

then

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta' input
ThreadCrash.o : ThreadCrash.cpp ThreadCrash.h hdr1.h  ../inc/hdr2.h ../inc/hdr3.h  ../inc/hdr4.h ../inc/hdr4.h
```

and finally

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta' input | sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+(: )?/ \1\\\n/g'
ThreadCrash.o : \
ThreadCrash.cpp \
ThreadCrash.h \
hdr1.h \
../inc/hdr2.h \
../inc/hdr3.h \
../inc/hdr4.h \
../inc/hdr4.h
```

You may be able to avoid the first step, if you can figure out how to prevent `gcc -MM` from splitting across lines in the first place.

Reference:

- [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one), *39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\"*